# Rails 3: Creating a unique URL for a view with a unique Partial rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

The best example I can find of this is the URL of a google images page with a particular image selected. The URL changes for each image that is selected.

In my case, I have a Notebooks model and a nested Notes model. In the view showing all the notes, when the user clicks a note he/she is taken to the Note show view. Instead, I would like them to be shown a partial within the same view, but I'd like the URL to change to include info about the selected note.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `replaceState()` in javascript. When the user clicks on the notes you open the note any way you want (using an ajax call for instance) and then when it's open you use a callback to fire the `replaceState()` function that will replace the current url with whatever you want (I suppose the url of your note).

Then, when a user comes into you site with this precise url you can parse the url to show the note he requested (or let Rails default behaviour redirect him to your note show view).

Here is the documentation for `replaceState()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState().C2.A0method

Here is a non working example of the corresponding view using jquery to illustrate my point:

```
= link_to "note", note_path(@note), id: 'x_link'

<script>
    $('#x_link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault() //we do not let the event propagate
        href = $(this).attr('href') //we get the href attribute of our note
        $.get(href, function(data) {
            show_partial(data) // write some method to display you partial
            history.replaceState(null, null, href) //replace the current state
        })
    })
</script>
```